# Limit of Alternating Sequence $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (-1)^x\frac{2x+3}{5x-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How would I take $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (-1)^x\frac{2x+3}{5x-1}$

The answer is DNE

I understand how to take limit without the alternating $(-1)^x$ function (which would be $2/5$), but what is the proper way to do this problem?

As I understand it, the absolute value theorem does not work because the limit does not = $0$

Comment: corrected . . .

Comment: this diverges I think. It alternates between $-2/5$ and $2/5$

Comment: Consider the subsequences of even and, respectively, odd indices and show that they both converge, but to different limits. P.S. For sequences it's more common to use $n$ for an index, rather than $x\,$.

Comment: yes it is divergent , but i would like to know how the limit is taken with the alternating (-1)^n to satisfy divergence test

Comment: @dxiv so is it safe to say that ignoring (-1)^x or any alternating function would be ok when taking limit specifically for divergence test

Comment: `how the limit is taken` Not sure what you mean by that. The limit does not exist, since not all subsequences have the same limit. Then, how do you mean to `take` it?

Comment: @dxiv my notes say limit = 2/5 but i could be wrong *EDIT: you are correct

Comment: Then either your notes are wrong, or something got lost in transcribing the question..

Comment: @dxiv would it be safe to say that limit will not exist when it is an alternating sequence?

Comment: @mathguy no, for example $(-1)^n n^{-1} \to 0$.

Comment: alternating sequences only converge when they go to 0, or you can split it up into an alternating sequence that goes to 0 and other sequences that converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any convergent sequence, any infinite subsequence converges to the same limit as the original sequence. In your case, the even-indexed subsequence converges to a nonzero limit which is the negative of the limit for the odd-indexed subsequence. Thus the sequence does not converge.